# Artifactory cli - download existing files

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm using a JFROG cli to download content from an Artifactory. It seems that even though a destination contains same files, cli is trying to download it. If I re-run the command without cleaning the destination folder, I takes the same time.
Is there any option to speedup the process? If destination folder has the same SHA1 file, skip?
Our command (download all folders a* in the repo):

```
jfrog rt dl --threads=`nproc` repo_name/a*/ $TMP_FOLDER/
```

Answer (score 1):

JFrog CLI is already skipping download in case of a file existence which is validated using a checksum.
You can see this by setting the environment variable "JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG" and then running same download command again. In the debug log you will see on some files the following line: "File already exists locally" - this means the download was skipped due to a file existence.
The relevant code can be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/blob/master/jfrog-client/artifactory/services/download.go#LC380) - see the method "downloadFileIfNeeded".
Keep in mind that the CLI still has to get the file info from Artifactory and calculate the local file checksum, so in case of a lot of small files, this won't have a strong effect as on big files download.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dima!
I'm downloading and uploading to a different instance large repo (500G) that contains many small and large files. Seems that my downloading process doesnt change files that already exists in the dest folder (modify date not changed). However, we feel that for large files, it takes the same time as if the file was downloaded.   
My motivation is to migrate a repo between two instances in two bulks: first migrate all (will take along time) with no downtime for users, second with users downtime will be short since most of the files are migrated.

Comment: Keep in mind, such migration will cause loss of properties and file statistics.   
As for the large files issue, I did some tests on my machine and I had a significant performance improvement on my second download. However different hardware can give different results.  
Fill free to open an issue in [JFrog CLI GitHub repository](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go). If you decide to do so, please provide us the measurements you did, your os type and hardware details (network speed and storage type especially important).